# Command$() worked in Access 2007 but does not work in Access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

Items using:

1. Access 2013 Database Source is the .accdb (referenced as "Source")
2. Access 2013 Database .accde of the source. (referenced as "CurrentVersion")
3. The user has a copy of the CurrentVersion on their C:\AccessSystems folder (referenced as "UserVersion")
4. SQL Database table linked to "Source" named `VersionControl2013`.
   Table contains:  `System_Name`, `Version_Number`, `MDE_Path_Name` and `MDE_Name`.

The flow:

1. Developer makes a change in Source
2. Developer updates the Category to the next version number.  Category is in the Databases properties.
3. Developer creates CurrentVersion and saves it to P:\ drive (where all the CurrentVersions are saved).
4. User opens UserVersion and code runs to check to see if it matches CurrentVersion.
5. User opts to update and code runs to close UserVersion and copy CurrentVersion to User's c:\AccessSystems folder.

Now... User is up to date with correct version.

UserVersion is opened by the user, on opening it checks to see if the version matches using below code:

```
Public Sub CheckVersionNumber()
   Dim SQLConn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim AnswerSet As New ADODB.Recordset
   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   Set cnt = dbs.Containers!Databases
   Set doc = cnt.documents!SummaryInfo
   doc.Properties.Refresh
   Set ThisVersion = doc.Properties("Category")
   Set SystemName = doc.Properties("Title")
   Set SQLConn = New ADODB.Connection
   SQLConn.Provider = "sqloledb"
   SQLConn.Open "Data Source=scgcserver1;Initial Catalog=SCGCDatawarehouse "
   QueryString = "SELECT VersionControl2013.* FROM VersionControl2013 WHERE (((VersionControl2013.System_Name)=" & "'" & SystemName & "'" & "));"
   AnswerSet.Open QueryString, SQLConn, , adCmdText
   If AnswerSet.EOF = False Then
      If RTrim(AnswerSet("Version_Number")) = ThisVersion Then
      Else
         MsgBox ("Version Number does not match")
         ServDir = "p:\accesssytems"
         Shell "MsAccess.exe " & "P:\AccessSystems\VersionControl\VersionControl2013.accde"
         Application.Quit
      End If
   End If
   AnswerSet.Close
   With SQLConn
       .Close
   End With    
End Sub
```

Note: The code below works in Access 2007.  It will not work in Access 2013.

When CurrentVersion is called and opened it runs the code below:

```
    Public Function LoadVersion()
     DialogMessage = "You have a previous version of the Application, Do you want to UPDATE your version?"
     DialogStyle = vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1
     DialogTitle = "Update Application"
     DialogResponse = MsgBox(DialogMessage, DialogStyle, DialogTitle)
     If DialogResponse = vbYes Then
        ApplicationName = Command$()
        Call GetApplicationInformation
        DoCmd.Hourglass True
        ToDirectory = "C:\AccessSystems\" & RTrim(DatabaseName)
        FromDirectory = RTrim(MDEPathName) & RTrim(DatabaseName)
        FileCopy "p:\AccessSystems\compiles\Access2013Compiles\" & DatabaseName, "c:\AccessSystems\" & DatabaseName
        MsgBox ("Your Client Copy has been updated  - Thank You " & " " & ApplicationName & " " & DatabaseName)
        Shell "MsAccess.exe " & "C:\AccessSystems\" & RTrim(DatabaseName)

        Application.Quit
     End If
End Function


Public Sub GetApplicationInformation()
   Dim SQLConn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim AnswerSet As New ADODB.Recordset

   Set SQLConn = New ADODB.Connection
   SQLConn.Provider = "sqloledb"
   SQLConn.Open "Data Source=scgcserver1;Initial Catalog=SCGCDatawarehouse "
   QueryString = "SELECT VersionControl2013.* FROM VersionControl2013 WHERE (((VersionControl2013.System_Name)=" & "'" & ApplicationName & "'" & "));"
   AnswerSet.Open QueryString, SQLConn, , adCmdText
   If AnswerSet.EOF = False Then
      DatabaseName = AnswerSet("MDE_Name")
      MDEPathName = AnswerSet("MDE_Path_Name")
   End If
   AnswerSet.Close
   With SQLConn
       .Close
   End With

End Sub
```

I get a runtime error

> 52: Bad file name or number.

Debug takes it to line and `DatabaseName` is "".

```
FileCopy "p:\AccessSystems\compiles\Access2013Compiles\" & DatabaseName, "c:\AccessSystems\" & DatabaseName
```

I feel the line: `ApplicationName = Command$()` has something to do with it because `ApplicationName` is blank also. It is supposed to bring in the application's name.

Why does it work in 2007, but not in 2013?

Comment: Interesting tidbit you left out that the `VersionControl2013` table is a SQL Server database. Please note SQL is a programming language which many RDMS's use including Oracle, SQL Server, Postgre, MySQL, DB2, SQLite, and even MS Access with the Jet/ACE SQL engine!

Comment: Also, why are you running an ADO connection on a linked table, namely on `VersionControl2013`? If available in current database as a linked table in current file, use MS Access' [DLookUp()](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php). You already connected ODBC when establishing the linked table. No need to do it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a rather convoluted system you have there.

The [`Command()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-Function-fec67826-7fd7-48ed-a7aa-479c020ffaa4) function returns a string that was appended to the Access command line with the /cmd switch.

You'd have to launch Access e.g. like this

```
"MSACCESS.EXE C:\mypath\Database1.accdb /cmd SomeString"
```

then if Database1.accdb calls `Command()`, it returns "SomeString".

But if I understand you correctly, the upper code launches the lower code with

```
Shell "MsAccess.exe " & "P:\AccessSystems\VersionControl\VersionControl2013.accde"
```

There is no /cmd switch, so `Command()` won't return anything.
Did it perhaps get lost in the switch to Access 2013?

---

**EDIT:**

As I wrote above, `ApplicationName = Command$()` cannot work in the lower code, because no `/cmd` string is passed here:

```
Shell "MsAccess.exe " & "P:\AccessSystems\VersionControl\VersionControl2013.accde"
```

It is used here:

```
WHERE VersionControl2013.System_Name = " & "'" & ApplicationName & "'"
```

so you need to pass whatever is the correct `VersionControl2013.System_Name`, like this:

```
Shell "MsAccess.exe " & "P:\AccessSystems\VersionControl\VersionControl2013.accde /cmd mySystemName"
```

Or if `System_Name` is simply the database (UserVersion) name, something like this:

```
Shell "MsAccess.exe " & "P:\AccessSystems\VersionControl\VersionControl2013.accde /cmd " & Dir(CurrentDb.Name)
```

I used `Dir()` to extract the file name from the full path.

Comment: Okay...I tried both suggestions and no progress.  Any other ideas?  Thanks again!

Comment: Use `Application.CurrentProject.FullName` which returns the path and name of current database file.

Comment: Thank you!  I used Andre451's Edited suggestion.  It is working! :)  I ended up changing all the "DatabaseName" to "ApplicationName" so it was consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am not seeing all the code or missing something but... normally you need to declare DatabaseName as a public variable available to all subroutines.
Or .. pass the values back to the calling statement.

Call like this:

```
databasename = GetApplicationInformation()
```

The function would look like this:

```
Public Function GetApplicationInformation() As String
... 
GetApplicationInformation =  AnswerSet("MDE_Name") ' the database name
```

But of course this does not explain why it worked in Access 2007. perhaps some more detail from you would help.

Comment: Thank you...I will try Andre451's suggestion first and if it does not work...I will try your suggestion.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions and neither worked.  Somehow I need to pass the "UserVersion" database name to the LoadVersion Code...ApplicationName.

Comment: @dspanogle's answer should work as you need to return DatabaseName from a function not subroutine. Check to see if Databasename is empty by adding a `debug.Print DatabaseName` just before `AnswerSet.Close` in `GetApplicationInformation()` sub and see output in the Immediate Window at bottom. Also check in SQL Server, the `VersionControl2013` table and see if very first record contains data in `MDE_Name` field which is the row you are querying. Wouldn't new version be last record?